# No se como seguir con mi codigo en C

Tags: c, funciones, return

Holaa espero que se encuentren bien...
Les cuento, estoy empezando a aprender el lenguaje C y entre las cosas que mas me cuentan de este lenguaje son las funciones. En esto caso quise desarrollar un programa que le pida dos numeros al usuario y que luego los sume, e imprima el resultado.
El caso es que solo pude llegar a  hacer la parte de solicitar los dos numeros pero no se como plantear la funcion aqui...
Si hago una funcion por separado donde directamente pongo los dos numeros ahi si me sale.
Intenté hacer este mismo ejercicio en Python y me salió sin problemas, lo que sucede es que yo estoy mas acostumbrado a escribir en python (hice dos cursos con certificación y todo), pero como ahora entré a la la universidad, tengo 18 años, me va a dar C en lugar de Python pues es un cambio muy pesado para mi por la gran cantidad de diferencias que tienen ambos como las palabras y funciones :/
Hasta el punto de que a veces se me llegan a mezclar ambos lenguaje y lo que debería de escribir como va en C lo escribo similar a como es en Python.
Apenas y con algo de ayuda de chat gpt, lo único que logré entender hasta el momento en C son los condicionales y como contanenar variables con texto.

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

```
  int num1;
  int num2;

  printf("Por favor ingrese un 
  numero:"\n);
  scanf("%d",&num1);
  printf("Por favor ingrese otro 
  numero:"\n);
  scanf("%d",&num1);

  printf("Ha seleccionado los 
  numeros: %d y %d"\n);
  printf("Ahora procederemos con 
  la suma"\n);
```

}

Comment: Por favor ponga su código como texto no como un imágen

Comment: Mucho texto. **¿Cuál es la pregunta?** Por cierto, el `\n` va dentro del string, igual que en Python. Algunas diferencias clave para que tengas en cuenta: toda variable o función debe tener tipo y las comillas simples son literales de caracter, no es indistinto como en Python.

Answer (score 0):

Solamente crea un variable , como int suma  y ponele suma = numero 1 + numero2 .Animo a mi tambien me costo C cuando empeze a programar

Comment: Vere si me sirve, gracias. Y si, cuesta mucho entender C, este lenguaje es muy diferente a Python.

Comment: Eso dentro del int main, o en un int aparte?

Comment: @Lautaro como habrás visto es mejor poner respuestas que no necesiten más explicación

Comment: @DiegoSebastianDiLuca Aca tenes un problema mas grande, para empezar.. tu pregunta esta bien, la respuesta esta incompleta, pero tu problema es pensar que python era un lenguaje de programacion, cuando solamente es un lenguaje de scripting... olvidate todo lo que viste ahi, y empieza de nuevo. Estudia C desde c, no uses chat gpt para eso porque te va a confundir mas... tu primera funcion, es int main... despues podes crear todas las funciones que quieras... y ellas van a delvolver un valor (como main, que devuelve un int)... pero empeza por leer el manual de C...

Comment: Cuando habia hecho los dos cursos de python durante la secundaria, el profe decia que era un lenguaje de programación...

Comment: Donde puedo encontrar material sobre C?

Comment: @DiegoSebastianDiLuca no esta mal lo que decia tu profe, pero por la forma con la cual trabajas con el, es en realidad un lenguaje de scripting (no se compila) y por lo tanto tiene otro tipo de facilidades, que en C no vas a tener. Todo lo que quieras sobre C, lo vas a encontrar en google. Pero te recomiendo empezar por el principio, Python hace muchas cosas raras (inclusive con las iteraciones) que no vas a poder hacer en un lenguaje de programacion real.

Comment: No sabía que es un lenguaje de script. Aunque por lo visto también es un [lenguaje de programación](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)

Answer (score 0):

creo que buscas algo como lo siguiente, primero debes de poner el valor que va a retornar tú función (int), seguido del nombre (en este caso suma) y en caso de que llevara algún parámetro iría dentro del paréntesis , es importante destacar que como en este caso es una función que retornará algo en el return debes escribir algo que sea del mismo tipo de dato que definiste inicialmente.

¡Saludos!

```
  int suma() 
{
    int num1=0,num2=0;
  printf("Por favor ingrese un numero: \n");
  scanf("%d",&num1);
  printf("Por favor ingrese otro numero: \n");
  scanf("%d",&num2);

  printf("Ha seleccionado los numeros: %d y %d \n");
  printf("Ahora procederemos con la suma \n");
  
  
  return num1+num2;
}

int resultado = suma();
printf("El resultado es: %d",resultado);
return 0;
```